# How to add actionbar and toolbar in a single activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-tabhost

I want to make an app with navigationDrawer, TabHost and ViewPager. I want to support from `API 8`. I am adding what I have achieved so far. Now getting error when uncommenting the commented statements in the main activity. How can I resolve this? Is there any alternative way of doing this?

`MainActivity.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmnetManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmnetManager));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                 actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(pos);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
//        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
//        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
//        tab1.setText("TABONE");
//        tab1.setTabListener(this);
//        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
//        tab2.setText("TABTWO");
//        tab2.setTabListener(this);
//        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
//        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (i == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

`FragmentOne.java`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {    
    public FragmentOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`app_bar_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`content_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I uncomment the commented statements it causes an force close. Error is This Tab configuration cannot be applied, I guess that It is because, using the Actionbar and Toolbar in the same activity. How can I resolve this? Is there any alternative methods to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You methods you are calling for the tabs on the actionbar are deprecated and will not work on a Toolbar. Use TabLayout from the design library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use the design library from google.